# Changing size of my divs while keeping it centered

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

I am trying to copy this site https://62bc5048ee1d4.site123.me.
I have trouble with menu page, everything was going well until it came to media query of `1000px`, I can change size of my `divs` but they are not centered:

```css
#part3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

#S1 {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 140px;
  padding-left: 150px;
}

#S2 {
  padding-left: 150px;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 140px;
}

.menu-h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-box1 {
  position: relative;
  left: -130px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 175%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.menu-img {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.menu-box2 {
  position: relative;
  left: -130px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 175%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

and finally its media-query : @media all and (max-width:1200px) {
  .topper-header {
    font-size: 240%;
  }
  #S1 {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
  #S2 {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
  .menu-h2 {
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width:1000px) {
  .topper-header {
    font-size: 170%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu-h2 {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  #S1 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  #S2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .menu-img {
    width: 235px;
    height: 150px;
  }
  .menu-box1 {
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    width: 135%;
  }
  .menu-box2 {
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    width: 135%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="part3">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="topper-header">RESTAURANT MENU</h1>
    <div id="S1">
      <h2 class="menu-h2">Main Menu</h2>
      <div class="menu-box1">
        <img class="menu-img" src="images/first1.jpg" width='255' height="170" />
        <h2>Pasta</h2>
        <p>Pasta with sheep's milk ricotta,</br> spinach, tomato sauce and basil</p>
        <span class="price">$ 31,99</span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-box1">
        <img class="menu-img" src="images/first2.jpg" width='255' height="170" />
        <h2>Pasta</h2>
        <p>Pasta with sheep's milk ricotta,</br> spinach, tomato sauce and basil</p>
        <span class="price">$ 31,99</span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-box1">
        <img class="menu-img" src="images/first3.jpg" width='255' height="170" />
        <h2>Pasta</h2>
        <p>Pasta with sheep's milk ricotta,</br> spinach, tomato sauce and basil</p>
        <span class="price">$ 31,99</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="S2">
      <h2 class="menu-h2">Desserts</h2>
      <div class="menu-box2">
        <img class="menu-img" src="images/second1.jpg" width='255' height="170" />
        <h2>Pasta</h2>
        <p>Pasta with sheep's milk ricotta,</br> spinach, tomato sauce and basil</p>
        <span class="price">$ 31,99</span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-box2">
        <img class="menu-img" src="images/second2.jpg" width='255' height="170" />
        <h2>Pasta</h2>
        <p>Pasta with sheep's milk ricotta,</br> spinach, tomato sauce and basil</p>
        <span class="price">$ 31,99</span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-box2">
        <img class="menu-img" src="images/second3.jpg" width='255' height="170" />
        <h2>Pasta</h2>
        <p>Pasta with sheep's milk ricotta,</br> spinach, tomato sauce and basil</p>
        <span class="price">$ 31,99</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

You can see that when my screen size I lower than `1000px` my `divs` are not entered, I am making them smaller but they are not centered,

Comment: I didn't quite understand what do you actually want?

Comment: have you tried my code?you can see that when my screen size I lower than 1000px my divs are not entered,im making them smaller but they are not centered,i want to fix that problem

Answer (score 1):

You've probably figured it out already, but here is my solution.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

#part3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 30px;
}

#part3>h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.menu-item {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f7f9f8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.menu-item>section {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.menu-item>section>* {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.menu-item>section>p,
h4:nth-of-type(2) {
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-item img {
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    .menu-item {
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        display: flex;
    }

    .menu-item>section {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .menu-item>section>p {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .menu-item img {
        width: 40%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

    .menus {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .menus>* {
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="part3">
        <h3>Restaurant Menu</h3>
        <section class="menus">
            <div class="main-menu">
                <h3 style="text-align: center">Main Menu</h3>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <img src="https://static1.s123-cdn-static-a.com/uploads/2031/800_5a15ac20180ec.jpg">
                    <section>
                        <h4>PASTA</h4>
                        <p>Pasta with sheep's milk ricotta, spinach, tomato sauce and basil</p>
                        <h4>$13.50</h4>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <img src="https://static1.s123-cdn-static-a.com/uploads/2031/800_5a15ac20180ec.jpg">
                    <section>
                        <h4>PASTA</h4>
                        <p>Pasta with sheep's milk ricotta, spinach, tomato sauce and basil</p>
                        <h4>$13.50</h4>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <img src="https://static1.s123-cdn-static-a.com/uploads/2031/800_5a15ac20180ec.jpg">
                    <section>
                        <h4>PASTA</h4>
                        <p>Pasta with sheep's milk ricotta, spinach, tomato sauce and basil</p>
                        <h4>$13.50</h4>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="desserts">
                <h3 style="text-align: center">Desserts</h3>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <img src="https://static1.s123-cdn-static-a.com/uploads/2031/800_5a15ac20180ec.jpg">
                    <section>
                        <h4>PASTA</h4>
                        <p>Pasta with sheep's milk ricotta, spinach, tomato sauce and basil</p>
                        <h4>$13.50</h4>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <img src="https://static1.s123-cdn-static-a.com/uploads/2031/800_5a15ac20180ec.jpg">
                    <section>
                        <h4>PASTA</h4>
                        <p>Pasta with sheep's milk ricotta, spinach, tomato sauce and basil</p>
                        <h4>$13.50</h4>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```